# How do I grant my SharePoint app read permission for more than one list?:

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-apps

I have just created a new SP app, and granted it read permission for lists:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true" >
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list" Right="Read" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Then when I deploy the app to SharePoint Online, I get a dialogue where I have to choose only one list that my app can read from. I was under the impression that the above permission would be for all lists. Is there a way to grant permission for more lists post-deployment, or do I need one app for each list I want to read?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the scope of the app permissions request.
Basically, you need to change `Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/**list**"` to `Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web"`.

When you do this, the app has access to all lists in the site.

See this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383.aspx) for more information.